# Find data between dates in mongodb?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to get all the records which have been modified in last 10 days. In the database I've a column LastModifiedDate. Based on this I want to write filter query in MongoDB. 
Following is the format of collection Owner:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5b0ca634806bebc3584d9dc2"),
    "ownerKey": "WEST PIONEER LLC, ID",
    "isCorporation": true,
    "corpName": "WEST PIONEER LLC",
    "propertyMailingAddress": {
      "poBox": "",
      "street": "250 S 5TH ST",
      "house": "",
      "apartment": "2",
      "city": "BOISE",
      "state": "ID",
      "zip": "83702",
      "type": "UNKNOWN",
      "sources": [
        "SNL"
      ]
    },
    "contacts": [],
    "createDate": {
      "year": 2018,
      "month": 5,
      "day": 28
    },
    "history": [],
    "sources": [
      "SNL"
    ],
    "lastModifiedDate": "2018-05-29T01:00:36.533Z"
  }
]
```

I'm querying data using following query:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      date: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "$lastModifiedDate"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      date: {
        $gte: new Date((new Date().getTime()-(10*24*60*60*1000)))
      }
    }
  }
])
```

But this is not a filter query. I found a way with aggregation query, instead I want a filter query which I can execute in Mongo Compass.

Answer (score 0):

In the collection document mentioned above lastModifiedDate is a string . It needs to be converted to ISODate object before being subtracted. Below query should work.

```
db.owners.aggregate([{$project:{"_id":1,"cdate":{$dateFromString:{"dateString":"$lastModifiedDate"}}}},{$project:{"_id":1,diff_msecs:{$subtract:[new ISODate(),"$cdate"]}}},{$project:{"_id":1,diff_days:{$divide:["$diff_msecs",1000*60*60*24]}}},{$match:{"diff_days":{"$lte":10}}}])
```

The initial projection converts lastModifiedDate from string to IsoDate. The second project does a subtraction from current date followed by conversion from milliseconds to days and finally, comparing if the result is less than equal to 10.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. Can you please share a query version which could executable in MongoDB Comapss?